# Изучаю С ++ в Xcode и сейчас изучаю работу с файлами. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка

Tags: c++, xcode, fstream, txt

Мне выбивает ошибку, когда я ввожу fout и предлагает заменить на сout. Возможно это особенности среды Xcode. Тогда как это можно исправить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string path = "integers.txt";
    ofstream fillfile;
    fillfile.open(path);
    if (!fillfile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "ERROR OPENING FILE" << endl;
    }
    else {
        fout << "FILE IS OPENED";
    }
    fillfile.close();
}
```

Comment: нет такого стандартного обьекта fout, и у вас он не определен, скорее всего вам как раз cout и нужен

Comment: Исправить? написать `#define fout cout`...

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, вы делали по инструкции [отсюда](http://cppstudio.com/post/446/)

И при копировании забыли изменить `fout << "FILE IS OPENED";` на "имя вашего объекта" << "FILE IS OPENED", например: `fillfile << "FILE IS OPENED";` и, как сказал Ildar, объекта fout у вас просто нет. Просто перепишите fout на ваше имя объекта

Comment: И правда) Только изучаю программирование поэтому иногда тупняки ловлю. Большое спасибо))